# Ordering the result of a left join

Tags: mysql

This is the code i have:
The 'media_work' table has an 'order' field that indicate the order of the files.
I want to sort the result of the 'media_work' table to get the first item (image)

This code works but doesn't order the 'media_work'

```
SELECT work.id, work.title, media.file_name_thumb,media_work.order, 
COUNT(media.file_name_thumb) AS mycount
FROM work
LEFT OUTER JOIN media_work ON media_work.work_id = work.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN media ON media_work.media_id = media.id
GROUP BY work.id ORDER BY work.id DESC
```

This is the result

```
id   title          file_name_thumb                 order   mycount
-------------------------------------------------------------------
3    laatste        thumb_20101028134738_278.gif    1       3
2    test work add  thumb_20101028133811_893.gif    1       56
1    test werk      thumb_20101028132316_537.jpg    2       5
```

I want the order to be ordered Ascending so it'll be '0'

Comment: can you just order by media_work.order?

Comment: That works you say? I always though `GROUP BY` had to be used in combination with an aggregate function or include all selected columns (same as DISTINCT). Also, try showing an example of the results you're getting and how they differ to the results you want.

Comment: @Phil: `MySQL` allows this, though it won't work like @op wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select first `media` for each `work`:

```
SELECT  work.id, work.title, media.file_name_thumb,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    media_work
        WHERE   media_work.work_id = work.id
        )
FROM    work
LEFT JOIN
        media
ON      media.id =
        (
        SELECT  media_work.media_id
        FROM    media_work
        WHERE   media_work.work_id = work.id
        ORDER BY
                media_work.work_id, media_work.order
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `media_work (work_id, order)` for this to work fast.

Comment: This works nice, but I also want the count of 'media' table. How does this work?